# Mimic complex Postgres key relationships in Django

Tags: postgresql, django-models, orm, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a Django DB that I am building essentially to echo the relationships defined in a separate PostgreSQL DB.

The motive for using the Django DB is to circumvent API request restrictions on the PostgreSQL DB which I am only permitted to ping a certain amount of times per day and to reduce query times as I am only using a small subset of the data hosted in the PostreSQL DB.

I would like to set up my Django key relationships so that I can perform joins using Django ORM to the same results I would be able to by querieng the PostgresDB.  I understand I could use raw SQL to query my Django-defined DB using a connection / cursor, but would like to avoid that for security purposes (SQL injection).

Below is an example of some of the tables / relationships...

```
class TicketsModel(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    opened_by_id =  models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    open_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    closed_by_id = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    close_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    assignee_name = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    sn_wg_sys_id = models.TextField(null=True) --> group ID



class ContactsModel(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True) --> contact ID
    full_name = models.TextField(null=True)


class HierarchyModel(models.Model):
    cntc_person_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_1 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_2 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_3 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_4 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_5 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_6 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_7 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_8 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_9 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_10 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_11 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_12 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
    hier_supervisor_level_13 = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID


class GroupsModel(models.Model):
    sn_sys_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True) --> group ID
    workgroup = models.TextField(null=True)
    manager = models.TextField(null=True) --> contact ID
```

I would like to set this up so that I could perform queries / joins at the same level of detail that I would be able to using raw SQL, but with Django ORM.  Based on my reading so far, Djangos ForeignKey and ManyToMany fields don't seem capable of reproducing the same relationships.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Django DB`.  `Django` uses the supported database backends as described here [databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/). So I would use Postgres as the backend. As to raw queries see [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/), which among things covers passing parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Right, my bad on the phrasing.  It is a Postgres DB.